# error for uploading code to esp8266 module

Tags: esp8266

I am getting error for uploading code to esp8266 module. I have installed cp2109 drivers also but at the time of uploading getting follwing error message:

Sketch uses 344,292 bytes (32%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1,044,464 bytes.
Global variables use 32,276 bytes (39%) of dynamic memory, leaving 49,644 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81,920 bytes.
warning: espcomm_send_command: wrong direction/command: 0x00 0x08, expected 0x01 0x08
warning: espcomm_send_command: wrong direction/command: 0x00 0x08, expected 0x01 0x08
warning: espcomm_send_command: wrong direction/command: 0x00 0x08, expected 0x01 0x08
warning: espcomm_send_command: wrong direction/command: 0x00 0x08, expected 0x01 0x08
warning: espcomm_send_command: wrong direction/command: 0x00 0x08, expected 0x01 0x08
warning: espcomm_send_command: wrong direction/command: 0x00 0x08, expected 0x01 0x08
warning: espcomm_send_command: wrong direction/command: 0x00 0x08, expected 0x01 0x08
warning: espcomm_send_command: wrong direction/command: 0x00 0x08, expected 0x01 0x08
warning: espcomm_send_command: wrong direction/command: 0x00 0x08, expected 0x01 0x08
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

---

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Try pressing and holing the flash button while pressing reset once. After that you will see a blink of the blue LED, release the flash button and try again.

Comment: I have done the same process of Reset and flash button blue light blink but yet not able to upload code getting this error message now:                        Sketch uses 344,292 bytes (32%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1,044,464 bytes.
Global variables use 32,276 bytes (39%) of dynamic memory, leaving 49,644 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81,920 bytes.
error: Failed to open COM1
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

Comment: the board isn't in flash mode

Comment: Did you select the COM port properly because it is very unlikely that it is on COM port 1